# Someone is scanning my postfix/dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, unix, dovecot

There is someone scanning my mail server.

What can i do to block them?

i tried adding this and is not helping:

```
/etc/hosts.deny
ALL: 80.82.77.18
```

i see this in the log:

```
...
Aug 23 03:34:40 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(torcac@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: torcac)
Aug 23 03:35:17 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(roselia@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: roselia)
Aug 23 03:35:56 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(japan@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: japan)
Aug 23 03:36:35 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(berta@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: berta)
Aug 23 03:37:08 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(blue,193.169.252.176): unknown user (given password: 123456)
Aug 23 03:37:12 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(keely@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: keely)
Aug 23 03:37:49 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(marcelia@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: marcelia)
Aug 23 03:38:26 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(yate@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: yate)
Aug 23 03:39:02 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(silvie@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: silvie)
Aug 23 03:39:41 auth-worker(1664): Info: sql(seven@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: seven)ang@example.net,80.82.77.18): unknown user (given password: bang)
...
```

Comment: I think you should considering using a tool like fail2ban to prevent people trying to bruteforce your password?

Comment: That is a common thing on any online server. Typically people use something like fail2ban to block repeat offenders in their firewall rather than manually and with TCP wrappers

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look at that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [importgeek.wordpress.com](https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2017/01/15/fail2ban-prevent-postfix-brute-force/) :

1. install Fail2Ban

   : `apt-get install fail2ban`
2. To limit memory usage, add to /etc/default/fail2ban:

   `+ulimit -s 256`
3. Create a local config file /etc/fail2ban/jail.local to override settings in jail.conf:

   : `cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

   : `vi /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
[dovecot]
enabled = true
port = pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps
filter = dovecot
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry  = 3

[postfix]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp,ssmtp
filter   = postfix
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry  = 3

[sasl]
enabled   = true
port      = smtp,ssmtp,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
filter    = sasl
logpath   = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry  = 3
```

**Edit**

Fail2ban (Debian Squeeze) isn’t shipped with a configuration for Dovecot, so create /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/dovecot.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = (?: pop3-login|imap-login): .*(?:Authentication failure|Aborted login \(auth failed|Aborted login \(tried to use disabled|Disconnected \(auth failed).*rip=(?P\S*),.*
ignoreregex =
```

Restart fail2ban:

```
# /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
```

Comment: Did it work? i'm getting same scans but none of the config is blocking it.

Comment: It worked finally. Thanks for the post. Had to change my dovecot logpath to /var/log/dovecot.log. And failregex to include ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:auth|auth-worker\(\d+\)): (?:Info: )?(?:pam|sql|passwd-file)\(\S+,<HOST>\): unknown user\s*$